# How to retrieve fcm token after didReceiveRegistrationToken was called?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

is there a way to retrieve fcm token one more time when application was already launched but `func messaging(_: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String)` was not called?

I have tried a lot of including below method to force above method call it again:

```
    FirebaseApp.app()?.delete { _ in
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Maybe there is a way to retrieve it from FirebaseApp instance?

Comment: The documentation shows there is a way to retrieve it https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#fetching-the-current-registration-token

Comment: Thank you, indeed it is solution. It works;)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you import `FirebaseMessaging`

```
if let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken {
...
}
```